# Removing certain characters at the beginning of string

Tags: c++, regex, string, stl

Here's the usecase.

I have got a string with relative path to the folder. It's format may vary a little bit depending on where it came from (I am dealing with exported files from difference software).

For example: `./path/to/folder`, `/path/to/folder`, `path/to/folder`.

What I need to do is to delete all the characters `'.'`, `'/'` from the beginning of the string. Of course I can just do this manually in a for loop, but I thought maybe there's some kind of stl function exactly for such use-cases.

Comment: You tagged your question `regex`. Have you tried anything `regex`-related?

Comment: I can't get what is bothering you... just check if the first character is `'.'` or `'/'` and based on that delete the characters... and what `stl` has to do with your problem anyway?

Comment: If you are fine using c++17 and you really want to use STL, then give `std::filesystem` library a try, what you want to do can be done by creating a `std::filesystem::path p(your_path_string)` and then `std::filesystem::relative(p).string()` to get your required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought maybe there's some kind of stl function exactly for such use-cases

```
#include <regex>

const std::string src("./path/to/folder");
static const std::regex re("^\\.?\\/?");

const std::string result = std::regex_replace(src, re, "");
```

If you need more efficiency than what `<regex>` provides, do it manually.